# List items not floating left in IE10

Tags: css, css-float

So I've tried almost every solution posted on here for getting list items to float left in IE10. It works in IE8 and 9, but for some reason in 10 it stacks them on top of each other.

I've tried changing the doctype to include:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I've also tried to set the container div as overflow:hidden, I've done the same with the li element and have also removed the margin for the item. There was a recommendation to set the width of the li item, but given this is updatable text, I can't do that. I've also tried to use display:inline-block. All to no resolve...

Here's a code snippit:

```
    <ul id="menu-main-menu-left" class="main-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu1" link="http://placehold.it/300/ea3e59&amp;text=sandals"><a rel="menuitem">Sandals</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu2" link=""><a href="http://ssekodesigns.lc/how-to-tie/">How To Tie</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu3" link="http://placehold.it/300/ea3e59&amp;text=leatherbags"><a rel="menuitem">Leather Bags</a </li>
    </ul>

    .main-menu li{
   font-family: 'Josefin Slab', Times , sans-serif;
   font-weight:600;
   font-size:11pt;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   line-height:15pt;
   text-align:center;
   float:left;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0;
    }
```

Does anyone have advice on how to get these to display properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am downvoting this. Provide a minimal functioning code example, no linking please.

Comment: Its better to post a bit of code for the list. Also what have you tried?

Comment: Updated with code instead of a link.

Comment: Are you trying to get your `li` to stack from left to right across the page? What do you mean by display properly? What is `proper` in this context?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get them to float from left to right. In all browsers except for IE10 they float correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can usually be remedied by putting a fixed width on the containing div.